# CameraX not creats jpeg file on Huawei phone (maybe file is lost)

Tags: kotlin, android-camerax

I met this exception on two Huawei devices of the same model. It was very strange for me because the app worked normally during 3 month before it and successfully processed thousands of images on different devices. The exception occurred when my picture processing service didn't get a file (I suppose the file had not been created by CameraX). The full log is below. Problem occurred before here:

Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/atche.surveyorapplication/2023.11.07  08-27-32.0.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I can protect my code from the very exception. But I'm worry about the reason of it.
P.S. unfortunately now I have no access to the devices logs for more info. The app was re-installed and worked properly again.

`2023-11-09 14:39:04.044 26047-26047 HwViewRootImpl          atche.surveyorapplication            I  removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time 2023-11-09 14:39:04.072 26047-26047 AudioManager            atche.surveyorapplication            V  querySoundEffectsEnabled... 2023-11-09 14:39:04.109 26047-26047 MediaPlayerNative       atche.surveyorapplication            I  prepare MediaPlayer(0xb5286d40) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.137 26047-26275 MediaPlayerNative       atche.surveyorapplication            D  Message: MEDIA_PREPARED(1), ext1=0, ext2=0x0 2023-11-09 14:39:04.137 26047-26047 MediaPlayerNative       atche.surveyorapplication            I  prepare complete - status=0 MediaPlayer(0xb5286d40) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.159 26047-26047 PlayerBase              atche.surveyorapplication            V  baseStart() piid=3607 2023-11-09 14:39:04.164 26047-26047 MediaPlayer             atche.surveyorapplication            I  [HSM] stayAwake true uid: 10117, pid: 26047 2023-11-09 14:39:04.167 26047-26047 MediaPlayerNative       atche.surveyorapplication            W  Action:start, CurrentState:MEDIA_PLAYER_STARTED 2023-11-09 14:39:04.202 26047-26047 ImageCapture            atche.surveyorapplication            D  takePictureInternal 2023-11-09 14:39:04.209 26047-26047 CameraOrientationUtil   atche.surveyorapplication            D  getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=90, isOppositeFacing=true, result=90 2023-11-09 14:39:04.212 26047-26047 TakePictureManager      atche.surveyorapplication            D  Issue the next TakePictureRequest. 2023-11-09 14:39:04.242 26047-26493 Camera2CameraImpl       atche.surveyorapplication            D  {Camera@65d1208[id=0]} Issue capture request 2023-11-09 14:39:04.243 26047-26493 CaptureSession          atche.surveyorapplication            D  Issuing capture request. 2023-11-09 14:39:04.248 26047-26493 Camera2Cap...estBuilder atche.surveyorapplication            D  createCaptureRequest 2023-11-09 14:39:04.280 26047-26275 MediaPlayerNative       atche.surveyorapplication            D  Message: Unknown MediaEventType(6), ext1=0, ext2=0x0 2023-11-09 14:39:04.287 26047-26078 Gralloc3                atche.surveyorapplication            W  allocator 3.x is not supported 2023-11-09 14:39:04.576 26047-26047 TakePictureManager      atche.surveyorapplication            D  Issue the next TakePictureRequest. 2023-11-09 14:39:04.576 26047-26047 TakePictureManager      atche.surveyorapplication            D  No new request. 2023-11-09 14:39:04.812 26047-26725 BitmapFactory           atche.surveyorapplication            E  Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/atche.surveyorapplication/2023.11.07  08-27-32.0.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.813 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/atche.surveyorapplication/2023.11.07  08-27-32.0.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.813 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.813 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.813 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:115) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.814 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface.initForFilename(ExifInterface.java:5283) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.814 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface.<init>(ExifInterface.java:3946) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.814 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at atche.surveyorapplication.PictureProcessingService.getImageExifOrientation(PictureProcessingService.kt:385) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.814 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at atche.surveyorapplication.PictureProcessingService.access$getImageExifOrientation(PictureProcessingService.kt:34) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.814 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at atche.surveyorapplication.PictureProcessingService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(PictureProcessingService.kt:104) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.814 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.814 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.814 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.814 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W  Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.814 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.814 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.815 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.815 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.815 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8198) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.815 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.815 26047-26725 System.err              atche.surveyorapplication            W      ... 10 more 2023-11-09 14:39:04.815 26047-26725 QarthLog                atche.surveyorapplication            I  [PatchStore] createDisableExceptionQarthFile 2023-11-09 14:39:04.816 26047-26725 QarthLog                atche.surveyorapplication            I  [PatchStore] create disable file for atche.surveyorapplication uid is 10117 2023-11-09 14:39:04.817 26047-26725 AndroidRuntime          atche.surveyorapplication            E  FATAL EXCEPTION: ServiceStartArguments Process: atche.surveyorapplication, PID: 26047 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference at atche.surveyorapplication.PictureProcessingService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(PictureProcessingService.kt:114) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219) at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 2023-11-09 14:39:04.837 26047-26725 Process                 atche.surveyorapplication            I  Sending signal. PID: 26047 SIG: 9`

As the exception did not appeared again yet I can do nothing to solve this.

Comment: Sounds like an OEM bug. If you file it here, the CameraX team might be able to add a workaround for it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=618491&template=1257717

Comment: Thank you Xi. Unfurtunately both of devices are not ander my control. To solve this problem I wrote debug code for case of CameraX not creates a file.